# for looping to split and merge a dataframe not working

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have written a chunk of code which is rather long, and essentially it takes apart a dataframe based on the value of a column and then creates a new dataframe. I have 10 values of this column I would like to do this with, but everything I try (creating a function or a for loop, for  instance) stalls out somewhere.

First I subset the df , df, by species identity

`ca<-df[df$species ==ca & !is.na(df$species),]`

here is the head(ca)

```
 species       pot  A      B       C N   A.1      B.1   C.1  
1         CA 121 -34.99 -36.08 -36.10    NA     NA     NA     
2         CA  122 -35.75 -35.29 -35.77    NA     NA     NA     
3         CA  123 -36.94 -35.88 -36.17    NA     NA     NA     
4         CA  124 -35.89 -34.69 -35.54    NA     NA     NA     
5         CA  125 -35.91 -34.90 -35.85    NA     NA     NA     
6         CA  126 -35.99 -36.24 -35.44    NA     NA     NA
```

the tail of ca is

```
       species pot      A      B     C NA_NA   A.1    B.1    C.1
15         CA 135     NA     NA     NA    NA -14.47 -27.88 -37.09
16         CA 136     NA     NA     NA    NA -13.57     NA -36.39
17         CA 137     NA     NA     NA    NA -14.52 -29.51 -36.54
18         CA 138     NA     NA     NA    NA -13.53 -32.35     NA
19         CA 139     NA     NA     NA    NA -14.34 -31.20 -36.49
20         CA 140     NA     NA     NA    NA -14.03 -32.34 -36.51
```

I wrote the following code which is successful for my ultimate goal :

```
                      y = CA$pot[ ! is.na(CA$A.1)],
                      all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE) %>% 
    transmute(A.pot = x, B.pot = y) %>%
    merge(y = CA[ ! is.na(CA$A), c("pot", "A", "B", "ACMI_C")],
          by.x = "A.pot", by.y = "pot") %>%
    merge(y = CA[ ! is.na(CA$A.1), c("pot", "A.1", "B.1", "C.1")],
          by.x = "B.pot", by.y = "pot")%>%
    mutate(H=(B.1-B)/(A.1 - A))
```

But, I have 10 different identities of species, and need to run the workflow for each iteration (i.e. for i in df$species), but it isn't allowing me to do so with the following code

```
for(i in df$species){
species<-df[df$species =="i" & !is.na df$species],
species.index <- merge(x = species$pot[ ! is.na(species$A)],
                      y = species$pot[ ! is.na(species$A.1)],
                      all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE) 
}
```

I'm new to this so any help would be great. I also tried creating a function, with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: The `merge` part in your `for` loop is not clear.  It is showing that you are subsetting two vectors instead of data.frame

Answer (score 1):

Here, the `i` is value from each 'species', and it should be `unique` as well.   The subsetting is happening on the literal "i" instead of `i`

```
un1 <- levels(df$species)
species_list <- vector('list', length(un1))
for(i in seq_along(un1)){
  species <- df[df$species == un1[i] & !is.na df$species), ],
  species_list[[i]] <- merge(x = species[!is.na(species$A), ],
                  y = species[!is.na(species$A.1), ],
                  all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE) 
  }
```

Comment: ah, I see. it is telling me, though, that unique(df$species) is an invalid length argument for vector

Comment: @Skotani1  If you do `unique(iris$Species)` or `levels(iris$Species)`  - if it is a `factor` column

Comment: yeah that works just fine alone, as does unique(df$species), but in the vector argument it is not accepted as length

Comment: You meant `df$species == un1[i]` ? Try `df[df$species == un1[1] & !is.na(df$species),]` as a test

Comment: @Skotani1 It should work with vector as well `iris[iris$Species == levels(iris$Species)[1],]`

Comment: @Skotani sorry, there is a typo.  I should have initialized with `length` instead of `unique` in `species_list` initiation.

Comment: no problem, but the output doesn't work. what you call species_list[[i]] should be an index of x and y and it's just the same dataframe

Comment: @Skotani1 I think you are looping over each unique value of 'species' and the `list` is also of the same length as unique species length.  So, the idea is to loop over those unique values, subset the 'df', and `merge` it with the same dataset on a different criteria.  But that merge code on your post is not clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221400/discussion-between-skotani1-and-akrun).